# How to convert hex form dataframe to human readable form in python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, hex, pyodbc

I am trying to fetch varbinary form of data from mssql server and convert it into readable form.

```
def fetchdata(self):
    query = 'select * from xlstorage'
    df = pd.read_sql(query, self.conn)
    print(df.to_string())
    print(type(df))
    print(df.all)
```

id                                             xlfile
0   1  b'PK\x03\x04\x14\x00\x06\x00\x08\x00\x00\x00!... 
I am getting this kind of dataframe how to convert it into original file formate or string dataframe???

Comment: Is the binary object you are extracting an Excel document, e.g., an .xlsx file?

Answer (score 1):

check the **struct.unpack()** module. 
As we don't know what kind of data your string should contain, its hard to tell you, what **format characters** to use [see here](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/struct.html)

the struct module is used like shown below:

```
import struct

string =str(b'\x03\x04\x14\x00\x06\x00\x08\x00')

format = 'hhl'
a = struct.unpack(format, string)

print(a) #=> (1027, 20, 524294)
```

Comment: thank you for reply.I am having pandas dataframe .It is not working in my code.